# Переокрытие вопросов, неясные причины закрытия

Tags: обсуждение

На сайте относительно недавно и *постоянно испытываю непонимание выбора причины закрытия тех или иных вопросов*. Иногда оно совсем полное.
Вот пример: данный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1430893/%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-long-long-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-python-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F) с наличием принятого ответа закрывается с комментарием "Этот вопрос необходимо уточнить или дополнить подробностями". Так как на ответ я уже потратил время и считаю его полезным для целого ряда случаев (в том числе и точно для такого, так как ошибка на Фоксфорде никуда не исчезла), то я вопрос переработал и подал на переоткрытие.
Получаю через час: "повторное открытие сообщения провалилось. Исходные причины закрытия не были исправлены". **Поясните мне, пожалуйста, вот что требует уточнения в формулировке вопроса, или какие ещё подробности тут людям, не переокрывшим вопрос, могут требоваться?** Я, как правило, очень точно формулирую мысли.
Или закрывается он вообще по какой-то другой причине, а формальная причина выбирается, как попало?

P.s. Не знаю, за переоткрытие те же, кто закрывал, голосует, или кто-то другой.

Comment: imho обычно (по крайней мере это было с закрытыми-переоткрытыми вопросами, которые активно обсуждались в чате) за переоткрытие голосуют другие люди. Что касается вообще закрытия вопросов (кроме тех, что являются очевидным бредом). Тут есть ряд активистов, которые считают, что на сайте должны остаться только вопросы полезные (по их мнению) абстрактому массовому коню в вакууме. Вам просто не повезло, что их критическая масса заметила вопрос, на который вы ответили, прежде чем он скрылся во тьме времен

Answer (score 2):

Всё что тут моё личное субъективное мнение

Я посмотрел вопрос и ваш ответ. Не обижайтесь, но этот вопрос и ответ как минимум не несут никакой пользы будущим людям. В вопросе насколько я понял из обсуждения требуется (почти) невозможное, что значит, либо в школе допустили какую-то ошибку, либо ученик вообще не так понял учителя

Не буду исключать ошибку школы, но буду предполагать что вероятность очень мала, как минимум потому что школа крупная, много учеников и кто-то да и сказал бы своему преподу, что я не понял как в питоне использовать `long long`, на что учитель обратив внимение сразу сообщил бы тем, кто составлял это задание или исправился бы сам, если сам это делал

То что ученик не так понял учителя более вероятно, т.к. учитель мог для общей информации сказать, что в других языках есть `long long`, а ученик подумал что нужно это тут применить

Т.к. не понятно 100% чья эта вина, то должен быть опубликован как минимум полный текст задачи, со всеми дополнительными условиями, чтобы дать хоть какой-то объектвный и полезный ответ автору

А ваш ответ - это не то что не полезный, но он явно не объективный. Поймите меня правильно, я не говорю, что он бесполезный, но он субъективный. У нас в группе например было 30 человек и каждый учился по-своему. Я даже помню, когда к нам приходили первокурсники с просьбами подсказать как учиться, то каждый из нас говорил свой метод обучения, т.к. ему было удобнее так учиться

Исходя из всего этого, я скорее всего проголосовал бы за "Невозможно дать объективный ответ", если пришлось бы голосовать первым. Но причина "Этот вопрос необходимо уточнить или дополнить подробностями" вполне себе подходит как по мне

Comment: 1) Спасибо за такой подробный ответ. 2) Это ошибка на популярном сайте Фоксфорд, там это прямо впечатано в комментарий к заданию (в вопросе приведена цитата), т.е. это не один учитель сказал -  ситуация повторится. 3) Я не говорю, что предложенный мной метод - единственный. Но это не мнение, это - метод действий. Точно так же как и ответов на вопросы может быть несколько, с использованием разных методов (кто-то использует `replace`, а кто-то регулярное выражение, например). 4) При такой причине - что тут ещё уточнять или какие подробности добавлять? Сама задача только запутает понимание.

Comment: @Сергей Если ошибка в постановке задачи, то как по мне тем более никак не помочь. Надо обратиться к учителю, чтобы тот принял меры, нам как сообществу тут нечем помочь

Comment: Значит, причина неверная - "Этот вопрос необходимо уточнить или дополнить подробностями" невыполним.

Comment: @Сергей Почему? Всё что вы мне сказали, вы выясняли во время общения с автором, что значит что нет нужных подробнстей в вопросе из-за чего приходится всё уточнять и выяснять. Возможно и по другой более подходящей причине можно было бы закрыть, но перекткрывать такой вопрос точно не стоит